# Docker not keeping chown user settings

Tags: linux, docker

I have a small example Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN groupadd -f -g 1000 docker && useradd -ms /bin/bash docker -u 1000 -g 1000 && ls -la /home
RUN chown docker:docker -R /home/docker && ls -la /home
RUN ls -la /home
```

Which gives the output:

```
$ docker build -t tmp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu:22.04
 ---> 6b7dfa7e8fdb
Step 2/4 : RUN groupadd -f -g 1000 docker && useradd -ms /bin/bash docker -u 1000 -g 1000 && ls -la /home
 ---> Running in 58bee8aa4dfd
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   4096 Aug 11 15:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   4096 Aug 11 15:55 ..
drwxr-x--- 2 docker docker 4096 Aug 11 15:55 docker
Removing intermediate container 58bee8aa4dfd
 ---> dbd5d16e92d5
Step 3/4 : RUN chown docker:docker -R /home/docker && ls -la /home
 ---> Running in d76701c0765d
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   4096 Aug 11 15:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   4096 Aug 11 15:55 ..
drwxr-x--- 1 docker docker 4096 Aug 11 15:55 docker
Removing intermediate container d76701c0765d
 ---> 14ba02eee117
Step 4/4 : RUN ls -la /home
 ---> Running in c3373d418be8
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 11 15:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 11 15:55 ..
drwxr-x--- 1 root root 4096 Aug 11 15:55 docker
Removing intermediate container c3373d418be8
 ---> 0a6de3939320
Successfully built 0a6de3939320
Successfully tagged tmp:latest
```

Note that once the container is built, /home/docker is owned by root. Taking out the `chown` line has no impact. It's like the file permissions are not preserved when the layer is completed.

I am using:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.25, build 20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
```

I also was able to reproduce on a fresh VM image with the same version of Docker.

Comment: Unable to reproduce using podman on ArchLinux (rootless) and RHEL9 (rootful). Might be a Docker issue. FYI.

Comment: I'm thinking it may actually be a bug, so I've opened an issue: https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/4495

Comment: This appears to be a server configuration question that belongs on Server Fault instead. It doesn't seem related to the programming aspects of Docker (I came across this post as a bad Close Vote Review audit). Of course, if it gets removed/migrated, I recommend including an actual question in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is a bug in that specific version of docker
See the bug  here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/+bug/2029523

Comment: Looks like they have a fix for it in the wild already. You'll need to add 'jammy-proposed' to your repository and `sudo apt install docker.io/jammy-proposed`. More details on how to do this here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1451257/715104.

TL;DR> The problem comes from the specific version of Go that was used when compiling Docker.