# Dockerfile changes file owner to root between RUNs

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this very simple Dockerfile

```
FROM debian
RUN touch /foo \
 && chown backup /foo \
 && ls -l /foo \
 && sleep 10
RUN ls -l /foo
```

Should the owner of /foo be changed to 'root' or stay as 'backup' ?

Because when I run it... well, basically everywhere I could test it, the result is as expected: both `ls` returns 'backup' as user

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 backup root 0 Aug 12 16:02 /foo
[...]
-rw-r--r-- 1 backup root 0 Aug 12 16:02 /foo
```

But now, when I run it on my PopOS laptop that, I think, just updated Docker to
Docker version 20.10.25, build 20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
The the 2nd `ls` returns 'root' as owner ...

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 backup root 0 Aug 12 16:34 /foo
[...]
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 12 16:34 /foo
```

Additional test:
I put a `sleep` after the `chown` and monitored to see at what point the file changed owner

```
$ watch -n1 ls -la "/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/*/foo"
```

and it appears to me the 1st 'foo' is created with the right owner, but then creates another subvolume (the snapshot for the image, I guess) and this is this one that has the wrong(?) owner.

Please tell me this is a bug and they're going to fix it and not a new "feature" because if not, this is going to be baaad for me ...

Comment: This is probably the same as [Docker not keeping chown user settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885161/docker-not-keeping-chown-user-settings); that suspects a bug in Docker itself (the file ownership in fact shouldn't change) but doesn't have a resolution.

Comment: I don't care if this was a dupe, its the one that Google found, and it's a super annoying bug.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this was indeed the same as
[Docker not keeping chown user settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885161/docker-not-keeping-chown-user-settings)

So, issues closed with an update of the OS.
cf. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/+bug/2029523