# Docker ubuntu 22.04 create user directory with non root ownership

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to build a docker image and create user "builder". This is the extract of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt update && apt install -y sudo
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash builder
RUN ls -al /home
```

The home directory is created with root as owner. Docker build command output:

```
Step 7/15 : RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash builder
---> Running in cdb06ab940c4
Removing intermediate container cdb06ab940c4
---> 3b4ee1d9f9d0
Step 8/15 : RUN ls -al /home
---> Running in 03b7a9bee771
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 17 07:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 17 07:14 ..
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Aug 17 07:14 builder
```

I have tried adding chown after addusr :

> "RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash builder && chown -R builder:builder /home/builder

but the home directory is still owned by root.

If I run ubuntu:22.04 with

> docker run -it ubuntu:22.04

I can create the user with command "useradd -ms /bin/bash builder" and the home directory will have correct permissions

I am using ubuntu 22.04. Docker version:

> Client:
> Version:           20.10.25
> API version:       1.41
> Go version:        go1.18.1
> Git commit:        20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
> Built:             Fri Jul 14 21:58:09 2023
> OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
> Context:           default
> Experimental:      true

> Server:
> Engine:
> Version:          20.10.25
> API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
> Go version:       go1.18.1
> Git commit:       20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
> Built:            Thu Jun 29 21:21:05 2023
> OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
> Experimental:     false
> containerd:
> Version:          1.7.2
> GitCommit:
> runc:
> Version:          1.1.7-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
> GitCommit:
> docker-init:
> Version:          0.19.0
> GitCommit:

Any hints?

Comment: Tried on **Windows** version 22.0.5 of Docker and it works, the folder is created with the correct permissions. I checked that on Ubuntu the latest version is 22.0.5. Try to update the docker engine, [instruction here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)

Comment: Is this the same problem as [Docker not keeping chown user settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885161/docker-not-keeping-chown-user-settings)?  That has a reference to a Launchpad issue.

Comment: (Reading the Dockerfile, my first response would be to tell you to _not_ create a home directory, since that's not usually useful in a single-process container, and definitely not to install `sudo`.  But that might be secondary to your issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. Solved by making user with no home directory as @DavidMaze suggested.